# .Net interface for a known return type, but unknown type/number of parameters

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, interface, azure

Is there a way to specify in an interface a known return type, but unknown number/type of parameters.

The reason I am asking is that I am using Windows Azure Table Storage and each table will have different Partition and Row keys with different input values.

I am creating a `ITableOperations` interface the code will be something like:

```
interface ITableOperations<T>
    where T : Azure.AzureTableEntity
{
    // Key specification
    string PartitionKey(/* ? What should go here  */);

    // Key specification
    string RowKey(/* ? What should go here  */);
}
```

And the item table... For another table, the input params would be different

```
public class ScheduledItem : ITableOperations<ScheduledPostEntity>
{
    public string PartitionKey(Guid userGuid)
    {
        return userGuid.ToString();
    }
    public string RowKey(DateTime dateScheduled)
    {
        return dateScheduled.ReverseTicks();
    }
}
```

Comment: How could you use this interface?

Comment: I just want to ensure that each class that uses this interface has the methods RowKey, PartitionKey that returns a string... There are other operations in the ITableOperations, basically the CRUD operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# supports multiple parameter in the form of an array by using the `params` keyword.

You could do this:

```
interface ITableOperations<T>
    where T : Azure.AzureTableEntity
{
    // Key specification
    string PartitionKey(params object[] data);

    // Key specification
    string RowKey(params object[] data);
}
```

If you already know the alternatives of parameters, then you can use overload.
Lets say you have a method that can either receive a string or a Guid or both, you could do this:

```
    string PartitionKey(Guid guid);
    string PartitionKey(string str);
    string PartitionKey(Guid guid, string str);
```

If you are using C# 4, then you can use optional parameters:

```
    string PartitionKey(Guid guid = default(Guid), string str = null);
```

Comment: Basically, the short answer for exactly what I am after seems like it cannot be done. Seems like using params object[] is the way. Thanks all. I've marked this as the correct answer as Miguel was the first to answer it, but everyone eluded roughly to the same answer

Answer (score 4):

You could try having a very generic interface.  For example:

```
interface ITableOperations<T, P, R>
    where T : Azure.AzureTableEntity
{
    string PartitionKey(P partitionKey);

    string RowKey(R rowKey);
}
```

Then your implementation could be:

```
public class ScheduledItem : ITableOperations<ScheduledPostEntity, Guid, DateTime>
{
    public string PartitionKey(Guid userGuid)
    {
        return userGuid.ToString();
    }
    public string RowKey(DateTime dateScheduled)
    {
        return dateScheduled.ReverseTicks();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Looking at some of your comments since I originally wrote this answer, you could come at it from a different angle.  The PartitionKey and RowKey won't change on your object once it has been created, so I'd almost take these particular functions out of this class and move it to the constructors of the classes that inherit from `AzureTableEntity`.  e.g.

```
public class ScheduledPostEntity : Azure.AzureTableEntity
{
    private Guid _userGuid;
    private DateTime _dateScheduled;

    public ScheduledPostEntity()
    {
        // Needed for deserialisation from Azure Table Storage
    }

    public ScheduledPostEntity(Guid userGuid, DateTime dateScheduled)
    {
        _userGuid = userGuid;
        _dateScheduled = dateScheduled;
    }

    public string PartitionKey
    {
        get { return _userGuid.ToString(); }
        set { _userGuid = Guid.Parse(value); }
    }

    public string RowKey
    {
        get { return _dateScheduled.ReverseTicks(); }
        set { _dateScheduled = value.FromReverseTicks(); }
    }

    // These are functions to avoid them being saved as additional properties
    // in Azure Table Storage.  Sometimes you can get away with them being
    // read only properties, but it depends on the type.
    public DateTime DateScheduled()
    {
        return _dateScheduled;
    }

    public Guid UserGuid()
    {
        return _userGuid;
    }
}
```

This has the advantage that whenever you create on of these objects, you know minimum requirements to save the object.  It also stops you from messing with things that will change your PK and RK.

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well. A good idea, but doesn't suit exactly what I am after as the partitionKey/RowKey could be made up with a number of properties ! I wish Azure Table Storage could hurry up and give us more control which columns can be indexed!

Comment: OK, I've added yet another idea which might help you out.

Answer (score 2):

You could define one parameter, which would be an array. This array would contain name/value pairs and could have as many as you need. I think this would give you the flexibility you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but ideally, specially when coding, I would want to see the signature so I know exactly what to pass in.. I did think about `params object`

Comment: @Jason I have code here that uses the params keyword. I'll post it but it's still not idea.

Comment: I think "knowing exactly what to pass in" might me mutually exclusive with wanting "unknown number/type of parameters."  You could overload the method for each signature but I think that would be a lot of overloads. Perhaps I don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

This still won't show you the proper list of parameters for DoStuff (you'll just see `params object[]`) but it's about as flexible as you'll get. Note that I've implemented the method explicitly in the implementing class so you don't see it in Intellisense if "foo" is declared as a `Foo` rather than an `IFoo`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IFoo foo = new Foo();
        foo.DoStuff(Guid.NewGuid());
    }
}

public interface IFoo
{
    void DoStuff(params object[] args);
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public void DoStuff(Guid arg)
    {
    }

    void IFoo.DoStuff(params object[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length != 1) throw new ArgumentException("args");
        if (args[0].GetType() != typeof(Guid)) throw new ArgumentException("args");
        DoStuff((Guid)args[0]);
    }
}
```